в Postman и получить данные методов
Из проекта SOAP UI задания "PIX' перенести в Postman и получить данные методов:
metod 1, metod 2.
Делаю все согласна заданию, переношу параметры, токен, но при выполнении выдает ошибку 403, кто может сказать почему?
Я понимаю что недостаточно прав у пользователя, но в SOAP UI облазел весь метод и никакого логина и пароля не нашел.



Значит как-то не так передаёте токен.  Обычно должен быть эндпойнт для логина, который выполняет аутентификацию и авторизацию, и возвращает требуемый токен.  Уточните детали, какая аутентификация у вас используется?

В этом АPI HTTP-заголовок для авторизации действительно называется token?
